# Why does nested presenter make the GWTP app running really slowly?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I am using GWTP to build my app. So far, I created 2 GWTP apps- 1 big and 1 small.

Both apps using nested presenter. That means it will have a parent presenter that represents the header and footer of a webpage. The header will have many links each link will take users to a child presenter accordingly.

Look at this simple website which has a header

```
Customer --- Registration ---- Search Product ---- LoginPanel
--------------------------------------------------------------

Content child presenter

--------------------------
```

Everytime I load my big app for the 1st time visit. It took like 20 secs. And it is 10 sec for the small app. I did a lot of code splitting but no help.

Seem "nested presenter" was not designed very well.

So, Why does nested presenter make the GWTP app running really slowly?

Comment: You should show some code, because I don't think nested presenters are slow. Also, the 20 secs you're referring to, is 20sec of loading when accessing the page, right? If you have long fetches while loading it might be why. But the question provides so little detail, that it's hard to answer.

Comment: If i run in Localhost then it is very fast. But if I run from website, then it is very long. So, it could be the my Virtual Private Server problem? I only pay 40$ a month for it.

Comment: I think looking at your queries could help. Also if your database is located far from your app's vps, it could be another reason for the slowdown.